# Limitation of Orientation doesn't work on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, flutter, ipad

I have application simply show the top page.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.copyWith(
      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent
    ));
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
      ),
      home: TopPage(title: 'flutter'),
    );
  }
}

class TopPage extends StatefulWidget {
  TopPage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  @override
  _TopPageState createState() => _TopPageState();
}

class _TopPageState extends State<TopPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);
  }
}
```

I limit the orientations by this

```
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
  DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
]);
```

It fix the orientation only portraitUp  on Android /Android Tablet/ iPhone.

However only in iPad.

It rotate to Landscape.

How can I stop rotation on iPad??.

---

In my Xcode `Deployment Info.` -> 1Device Orientation`

`Portlait`
`Lanscape Left`
`Landscape Right`

are checked.

Becase I need to rotate on pages other than `TopPage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, your app on iPad opts into iPad multitasking, and it is expected to rotate in all four orientations. Its implementation of the preferred orientations is not even consulted.

It can opt out by setting `UIRequiresFullScreen` in its *Info.plist*.